# How to JavaScript function returns value to PHP to catch

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form in HTML and a JavaScript function to be called after "Submit" button is pressed as below,

```html
<form id="get_content" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
  <h1>Header1<h1>
 <input type="text" id="title" name="title"><br /><br/>
 <h1>Header 2</h1>
  <textarea rows=8 cols=62 name="content" id="content"></textarea><br/>
 <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="js_function();" /><br/>
 <span name="result" id="result"></span>
</form>
```

And JavaScript code is similar to this:

```js
function js_function(){
 var result = document.getElementById("result");
 var txt_input = document.getElementById("title");

 var result_a = "Result A";
 var result_b = "Result B";
 var error_value = "Error Detected.";
  
 result.innerHTML = "Not Detected. Should default to what ever the user prefers. ";

 if (!is_result(txt_input)){
  result.innerHTML = "Send Error Code.";
        var result = error_value;
        return result;
 } 
 if (is_resultA(txt_input)){
  result.innerHTML = "Result A";
        var result = result_a;
        return result;
 } 
 if (is_resultB(txt_input)){
  result.innerHTML = "Result B";
        var result = result_b;
        return result;
 } 
 
}
```

Then I want to catch the return values from JS with PHP after the process. So I gave PHP snippet.  The JS function returns the correct value but the problem is that the return value from JS function seems NULL when PHP snippet interacts.

```html
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    $result_chk = $_GET['result'];
  
  
  if ($result_chk == 'Result A'){

   echo "This is A";
  }
  else if ($result_chk == 'Result B'){

   echo "This is B";

  }
   
  else {
   echo "ERROR";

  }
}
```

Is that because I called the "Submit" button in PHP again ? or Are there any possible ways to catch JS value to PHP without passing off before the PHP runs. I also tried passing value in URL from JS function, it also went off when PHP interacts.

Comment: try use `print_r($_POST)` and `print_r($_GET)` to see the data with php

Answer (score 0):

declare result as input field as

```
 <input value="" name="result" id="result"/>
```

and set it in JS as:

```
 document.getElementById('result').value='new value';
```

Once, the form is submitted, it will have the value in

```
  $_POST['result'];
```

I can see you have mentioned `$_GET` THERE

Comment: it's a valuable answer but still cannot solve the problem. Thank you for your real quick reply.